# recursive setTimeout() pause on background

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, settimeout

I have a piece of code:

```
var logo = $("#blinking-logo");
function logo_blink() {
    logo.fadeOut(10).delay(10)
        .fadeIn(10).delay(20)
            .fadeOut(10).delay(10)
            .fadeIn(10)
    window.setTimeout(logo_blink, (Math.random()*(1500))+1500);
}
logo_blink();
```

All it makes is blinking a picture once in ~30 seconds (time is less here for easier debugging)

The problem that Chrome pauses this timer while the tab in backgrounded, and then, when coming back to that tab, it blinks all the blinks that were missed in background.

I'd like to pause the timer while in background, but I don't know how. I've read some related posts, but it seems that they describe the opposite problem. Is there any way to detect the backgrounding of a tab?

Comment: There is something called [`requestAnimationFrame`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.requestAnimationFrame) that will pause when the tab isn't in the foreground, but it's not widely supported.  Here's an article about it: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2011/08/animating-with-javascript-from-setinterval-to-requestanimationframe/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a known feature. To conserve the resources Chrome does not update the window without focus :) You could check, for example, that window lost its focus and stop the timer. Start it again when window is in focus. For example:

```
var timer = null;
var logo = $("#blinking-logo");
function logo_blink() {
    if(timer) clearTimeout('timer');
    logo.fadeOut(10).delay(10)
        .fadeIn(10).delay(20)
            .fadeOut(10).delay(10)
            .fadeIn(10)
    timer = window.setTimeout(logo_blink, (Math.random()*(1500))+1500);
}
logo_blink();
$(window).blur(function(){clearTimeout(timer); timer = null;});
$(window).focus(function(){if (!timer) timer = window.setTimeout(logo_blink, (Math.random()*(1500))+1500);});
```

Something like this. On one of my pages with animation a had the same problem with setInterval, so I just pause it when the page is in background.

```
if (!$.browser.msie)
{
    $(window).focus(function(){paused = false;});
    $(window).blur(function(){paused = true;});
}
```

And than skipped animation based on the value of paused flag.

ps: Code is updated with optimization discussed below.

Comment: To avoid wasting CPU time and memory also when the window has the focus, should the first expression in `logo_blink()` be `if(timer) clearTimeout('timer');`

Comment: Works like charm =) And I'll agree with Teemu about clearing timer

Comment: @M2_           Might be, thanks for the hint :) I'll update the code.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome, Firefox and IE10 have page visibility APIs that you can use to determine when you page is no longer visible.  This works better than using focus in some circumstances.  Here's an example from MDN:

```
//startSimulation and pauseSimulation defined elsewhere
function handleVisibilityChange() {
    if (document.hidden) {
        pauseSimulation();
    } else  {
       startSimulation();
    }
}
document.addEventListener("visibilitychange", handleVisibilityChange, false);
```

And, some reference documents:

http://code.google.com/chrome/whitepapers/pagevisibility.html

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Using_the_Page_Visibility_API

W3 Document: http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/webperf/raw-file/tip/specs/PageVisibility/Overview.html

The only work-arounds I've seen for older browsers involve determining whether your window has focus or not which isn't perfect, but maybe better than nothing in some cases.

Comment: That seems more complicated, but looks like universal solution, especially if you don't use jQuery or something. Thank you!

Comment: @M2_ - It's actually a bit less universal (because it only works in modern browsers), but it's more accurate.  For example, this works when you have side-by-side browser windows, both visible and the focus method gets confused by that - it really only works for tabs where the unfocused window is never visible.

Comment: Oh, that's a nice approach too.

But do older browsers have that “time-freezing” mechanism on background? In case that `document.visible` works only in modern ones and solves the problem. I just wonder if the problem and solution came at once.

Comment: @M2_ - I don't understand what you're asking.  If you read the references I included, it explains which browsers support this.