# How can I pause a recursive setTimeout while I change tab(focus)

Tags: javascript, animation, async-await, settimeout

My Code:

```
  let isBlack = true;
  function animate() {
    $(".someDiv").animate({
      backgroundColor: isBlack ? "transparent" : 'black'
    }, 20);
    isBlack = !isBlack;
  }

  const delay = ms => new Promise(res => setTimeout(res, ms));
  async function animateAndWait(msArr) {
    for (let i = 0; i < msArr.length; i++) {
      animate();
      await delay(msArr[i]);
    }
  }

  flashFunction();

  async function flashFunction() {
    await animateAndWait([300, 50]);
    if (myRandomNumberBetween(1, 100) <= 10) {
      return delay(3000)
        .then(flashFunction);
    }
    await animateAndWait([300, 400]);
      delay(3000)
        .then(flashFunction);
  }
```

It makes a div blink a couple of times at a ~3 seconds interval.
My problem occurs when I switch tabs. That Browser pauses the timer while I am on another tab, and then, when I come back to this tab, it blinks all the blinks(rapidly) that were missed in background.

I would like to somehow pause the timer while in background or clear the interval. Some guys have asked the same question but I can't incorporate here the answers that have helped them. Or maybe I just don't know how. This might be well over my head but if someone has some time on their hands I would appreciate their help.

Here are some links from the guys with similar problems:

[recursive setTimeout() pause on background](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9040120/recursive-settimeout-pause-on-background)

[Animations pause when browser tab is not visible](https://greensock.com/forums/topic/10051-animations-pause-when-browser-tab-is-not-visible/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use  `window.onblur`/`window.onfocus` events to destroy/regenerate the Timeout when tab loses/recovers focus.

```
let myTimeout;

window.onfocus = function() {
  console.log('focus')
  clearTimeout(myTimeout);
  myAction();
};

window.onblur = function(){
   console.log('blur')
   clearTimeout(myTimeout);
};

function myAction(){
  /* 
     your code ...
  */
  console.log('new cycle')
  myTimeout = setTimeout( myAction, 1000 );
}

myAction();
```

> If you are looking for a timer capable of being paused/resumed take a look at this [tiny library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/advanced-timer)

Answer (score 0):

If some beginner like me wants to know how I combined my code with colxi's answer to my question here it is:

```
   let myTimeout;
   let isBlack = true;


    window.onfocus = function() {
      console.log('focus')
      clearTimeout(myTimeout);
      myAction();
    };

    window.onblur = function(){
      console.log('blur')
      clearTimeout(myTimeout);
    };

    function animate() {
      $(".playerInfoCoatTwo").animate({
        backgroundColor: isBlack ? "transparent" : 'black'
      }, 20);
      isBlack = !isBlack;
    }

    function myAction(){

      const delay = ms => new Promise(res => myTimeout = setTimeout(res, ms)); // some changes here

      async function animateAndWait(msArr) {
        for (let i = 0; i < msArr.length; i++) {
          animate();
          await delay(msArr[i]);
        }
      }

      flashFunction();

      async function flashFunction() {
        await animateAndWait([300, 50]);
        if (myRandomNumberBetween(1, 100) <= 10) {
          return delay(3000)
            .then(flashFunction);
        }
        await animateAndWait([300, 400]);
          delay(3000)
            .then(flashFunction);
      }
      console.log('new cycle') 
    }

    myAction();
```

However I have no idea if it is optimal or not. Nonetheless it works!